# Cannot resolve hostname

Tags: debian, dns, raspberry-pi, hostname, raspbian

I'm using a Debian on a RaspberryPi and the problem that I'm having is that I can't connect to the Internet.

Every time I try I see a message that says "cannot resolve hostname". From the terminal, I tried:

```
$ ping www.google.com 
unknown host google.com

$ ping 8.8.8.8
network is unreachable
```

output of 'ip addr list'

```
1: <LOOPBACK, UP, LOWER_UP> mt 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 vrd 00:00:00:00:00:00:
   inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: eth0: <BOADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 dis pfifo_fast state UP qlen 100
   link/ether b8:27:eb:18:b9:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

This appears after doing the ifdown eth0 and ifup eth0 as drobert suggest

```
  innet 1393.182.112.9116 brd 139.182.255.255 scope global eth0
    valid_lft forevere preferred_lft forever
```

ip route ls

```
139.182.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 139.182.112.9
```

etc/network/interface

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

address 139.182.112.9

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.cong
iface default inet dhcp
```

ifconfig

```
bcast: 139.182.255.255
Mask: 255.255.0.0
```

I try the up route list command nothing happed

Comment: please post the contents of the following commands: `ip addr list` and `ip route list`. Your problem seems to be the lack of a default route to your gateway.

Comment: @nwildner I update my question

Comment: Well, it seems that you don´t even have an ip address. Try `dhclient eth0` to aquire an address from your lan(if there is a dhcp server somewhere). Cheers :)

Comment: @nwildner nothing happend with the dhclient eth0 command :/

Comment: Your Pi isn't connected to any network. What kind of network connection does it have? Is there a cable plugged into `eth0` and if so what's at the other end?

Comment: Hi Carlos. Does `dhclient` even return error or no screen response? It seems that you have connectivity(`LOWER_UP` on ip addr list) but you don´t have a L3 configuration(addressing/routing). Other computers connected to this network aquire ip address automatically?

Comment: @Gilles yes it is connected using a cable, and I assign the ip address on /et/network/interface/ and still having the same problem

Comment: @nwildner no no error :/

Comment: @CarlosPerez Your `ip addr ls` output doesn't show an IP address. So for some reason the address you assigned in `/etc/network/interfaces` didn't take. I suggest `ifdown eth0` (ignore any errors) and then seeing if you get an error from `ifup eth0`.

Comment: @derobert I try with the ifdown eth0 and ifup eth0 and im still having the same problem

Comment: @CarlosPerez did either produce an error message? Also, does `ip addr ls` show the IP address now? Does `ip route ls` show your default gateway? If not, please edit your question to include the `/etc/network/interfaces` (if you want to obscure the IP addresses, feel free to do so).

Comment: @derobert yes now the ip show after running the command ip addr ls I update my question

Comment: @CarlosPerez I'm going to assume the weird 4-digit octets in the IP address are just a mistake in editing the question. It appears you don't have a default gateway; did you specify one (with the `gateway` clause) in your `/etc/network/interfaces`? Also, make sure you have `allow-hotplug eth0` or `auto eth0` in there somewhere (otherwise, it won't be started on boot).

Comment: @CarlosPerez (Also, check your netmask. It's possible 255.255.0.0 is right, but I doubt it.)

Comment: @derobert thanks for helping me, I update my question again, so you can see the etc/network/interface and the ifconfig. sorry but im reall y new at this :/

Comment: @CarlosPerez that is a very confused `/etc/network/interfaces`. Let me post an example as an answer, because I think that'll get it working for you. Keep in mind you must do an ifdown/ifup pair each time to make the changes take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `/etc/network/interfaces` is confused. There are several methods of assigning an IP address to the interface; you've specified `dhcp` which means to ask the DHCP server for an address. But then you went ahead and specified an address anyway.

I think what you want is something like this

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0         # omit this line if using ifplugd
iface eth0 inet static
    address 139.182.112.9
    netmask a.b.c.d
    gateway 139.182.e.f

allow-hotplug wlan0

iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

You hopefully know the right netmask and gateway. If not, you'll need to get them from your network administrator. They should have been provided along with the IP address.

Comment: wooow you are a genius man, thank you so much :))

Comment: wlan with hotplug?

Comment: @Braiam allow-hotplug should bring it up when udev gets the device. I don't think OP is running Network Manager. Also not sure if OP is even using the wlan.